# Open "chrome://bookmarks/" by Windows command

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, bookmarks, protocol, file-shortcut

It's fine to open a http url with Chrome by a Windows command like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe" "http://www.youtube.com"
```

But when I try to open an url of protocol  "chrome://" by command like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe" "chrome://bookmarks/#120"
```

, where the url is of a Bookmark Manager page, the result is opening the home page with a new Chrome window.

Is it possible to open a Bookmark Manager page with Chrome by a Windows command?

Actually, what I'm trying to do is to create a shortcut file on Windows Desktop for opening the Bookmark Manager page of a bookmark folder. The way I tried was to copy a Chrome shortcut to the Desktop, right click on it, select "Properties", and put the Windows command to the "Target" column. It works fine for any http url, but fails as I mentioned above for any "chrome://" url.

Thank you experts a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Steps to get shorcut on desktop:

- Open the bookmarks manager in a new window
- tap f12 key to bring up inspector
- switch to the network tab and do a refresh
- on the first request look at the headers tab and copy the request url (uses chrome-extension:// schema)
- if you run `$PATH_TO_CHROME\chrome.exe $URL_FROM_PREVIOUS_STEP` it whould work as intended
- paste the command above in a new shortcut (right click on desktop > new > shortcut)
- right click the created file and click properties. in the shortcut tab you can also assign a different icon

that's about it...

Comment: This only works for the bookmarks page (that was what the question was about so it's OK), but is there a way to do the same thing for for example the History page or the Settings page?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce this for Settings or History, apparently  the Bookmarks page behaves like some kind of a built-in extension, while the request url for the settings page is simply`chrome://chrome/settings/`. Since the response has a `X-Frame-Options` header with a value of `DENY`, it can't be rendered in a frame or anything. We might need a chrome guru for a better answer :)

Comment: I think you would need to disable web security. To do this you need to use a special switch and give it a temporary directory, so that it will create a temporary profile, for example: `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir=c:\tmp`

Comment: I couldn't get this working on Windows 11 in 2022 . . . :(

Comment: @AndreiC @DonaldDuck Any updates? My shortcut sadly opens Chrome's startup page :( "Target" is set to: `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "chrome://bookmarks/?id=22"` & "Start in" is set to: `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application"`. Funny enough, if I set Chrome's startup page to "chrome://bookmarks/?id=22", Chrome.exe opens to "chrome://bookmarks/?id=22". Confirming Chrome can be opened to the bookmarks page, making me wonder what code is used to do that. Does your method still work? Can you test it, maybe I'm just doing something wrong I hope.

Comment: @Bwizz this doesn't seem to work for me, running `google-chrome "chrome://bookmarks/?id=527"` from the linux terminal just goes to a blank tab. Same for settings or history. I haven't tried this on Windows.